# jhipster-registry behind a proxy

Tags: proxy, jhipster, jhipster-registry

In the jhipster-registry all the proxy parameters  aren't not taken into account and mainly  the nonProxyHost one.

At startup, the Jhipster-registry container will clone the project on github (via the proxy);

on the other hand, it can not contact the local services (eg keycloak) because it should not use the proxy (that it does because it does not seem to take into account the nonProxyHost parameter)

How could we solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

please take a look in the following link: http://www.jhipster.tech/configuring-a-corporate-proxy/.
I had an issue configuring the corporate proxy to run maven, then I just took a look in this page, there were all my answers on it. If your issue persist, please let know.

-Rod